# How to do the GPS location to show a route to a fixed destination in android with google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Here is the link of the old coding which I tried

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Also, I was searched many different sites which were about the current location to fixed destination, but these could not satisfy my requirement.

I need to:
When user open the application, will already have the destination marker on the map. User enable the location/GPS, the application will create the marker in user's location and show the route to the destination marker. When user are moving, the marker will also follow the movement and show the new route to the destination marker.

This is what I want to do it.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're close to violating the terms of use with this functionality: `No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.`  see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

Comment: As you said it. I cannot do the expect function in what I need? I can do what to finish my requirement?